# How to count author posts for a month ago

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show users published posts count for **a month ago** 
I use this code, but its show **all the date and time** posts count

```
count_user_posts($author_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to do it manually. Maybe using `WP_Query`. `count_user_posts()` function don't allow filter by date.

```
$args = [
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'author'            => $author_id,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'date_query' => [
        [
            'after' => '30 days ago',
            'column' => 'post_date',
        ],
    ],
];

$posts = new \WP_Query($args);
$total = $posts->found_posts;
```

More about `WP_Query` class: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/